# Tomcat 9 memory leak with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and NioEndpoint

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, tomcat9, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am trying to analyze cpu and memory spike in my system in kubernetes pods. After running the load test, when the memory usage did not go down, I took a heap dump and analyzed using MAT.
[image: Leak Primary Suspect]

[image: Outgoing class structure]

I am new to this code base. From what I can tell it uses, it uses PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager which uses NioEndpoint to establish a pool of connections. Uses FeignClient which in turn uses ApacheHttpClient which is set with HttpClient with connection manager. I see that the threads are stacking up and I can't tell why. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` (from [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/index.html)) does not use `NioEndpoint` (from Tomcat), which can be used only for incoming connections (HTTP server sockets).

The 500 instances of `SecureNioChannel` that you observe are a pool of buffers to serve up to 500 TLS connections concurrently. They are **not a leak**, but a feature that reduces the amount of garbage collection necessary to serve a request.

You can control this pool through several connector options (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#NIO_specific_configuration)):

- `socket.bufferPool` configures the size of the pool. If you set it to `0`, no cache will be created (but every request will create a new `SecureNioChannel` object),
- `socket.appReadBufSize` and `socket.appWriteBufSize` configures the size of each buffer. A `SecureNioChannel` uses two buffers of each kind.